# Extract Data Enclosed between three asterisks in python

Tags: python, regex

I want the data enclosed between three asterisks.And the Word should start with description.
For eg:I have data like
 `description ***tCore-DFON_P.17-18>dPLUC80115_S19P1>>><<<dPDCL80121_S17P1<100G.IPT.NTTA.SEA.ASE+PC1.LUC/PLD-SEA/PLD_100GEL064.263568***;`

I want only 
`tCore-DFON_P.17-18>dPLUC80115_S19P1>>><<<dPDCL80121_S17P1<100G.IPT.NTTA.SEA.ASE+PC1.LUC/PLD-SEA/PLD_100GEL064.263568`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "description ***tCore-DFON_P.17-18>dPLUC80115_S19P1>>><<<dPDCL80121_S17P1<100G.IPT.NTTA.SEA.ASE+PC1.LUC/PLD-SEA/PLD_100GEL064.263568***;"
matches = re.findall(r'\bdescription\s+\*{3}(.*?)\*{3}', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['tCore-DFON_P.17-18>dPLUC80115_S19P1>>><<<dPDCL80121_S17P1<100G.IPT.NTTA.SEA.ASE+PC1.LUC/PLD-SEA/PLD_100GEL064.263568']
```

Note that I use dot all mode in the regex, in case your expected matches might span across more than one line.

Comment: Thanks Tim ,Its working